# Integration by substitution using $u^2=3-x$

Tags: integration

The question says to integrate $\frac x{\sqrt{3-x}}$ using the substitution $u^2=3-x$.

What I did was first rearrange $u^2=3-x$ into $ 3 - u^2 =x$ and then subbed it into the integral .

I then rearranged $u^2=3-x$ to $u=\sqrt{3-x} $ and then also subbed that in.

Next I found the derivative of $u$ which I believe to be $du/dx = -1/(2\sqrt{3-x}$) I then sub in u and then rearrange to get $-2udu = dx $

I then also sub that in then have $y = -2(3-u^2)$ and integrate it.

However when i integrate it i get $-6\sqrt{3-x} + (2(3-x)^3)/3 $

But the answer is $(-2/3)(x+6)\sqrt{3-x} $.

I tried to rearrange my answer to get that, but I was unsuccessful. Is there instead a mistake in my working out?

Side note: I tried to put things to the power of a 1/2 but it did not work out I'm not sure how to do it

thank you

Comment: Put the exponents in curly braces (3-x)^{0.5}.

Comment: @JacobCheverie Thank you !

Comment: Your first step was wrong. $u^2=3-x$ doesn't rearrange to $x=u^2-3$, it rearranges to $x=3-u^2$.

Comment: write $x=(x-3)+3$

Comment: @JohnDoe That was a mistake in my typing out my working out i think because on my paper i wrote  $= 3−^2$  ill change it

Comment: @user639649 yep you're right, that's not where your mistake was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution, you got to $$\int -2(3-u^2)\mathrm du=\int(-6+2u^2)\mathrm du=-6u+\frac23u^3$$ignoring the constant of integration. $$-6u+\frac23u^2=\frac23u(u^2-9)=\frac23\sqrt{3-x}(-x-6)$$as required.

---

Where you went wrong was, you wrote $u^3=(3-x)^3$, when it should really have been $u^3=(3-x)^{3/2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Using $u^2 = 3-x$, we have the following

$$\int \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{3-x}} dx = \int \dfrac{3-u^2}{\sqrt{u^2}} dx = \int \dfrac{3-u^2}{u} dx$$

Now, like you did, solve the transformation for $u$ such that $u=(3-x)^\frac{1}{2}$. Then, $du = -\dfrac{1}{2}(3-x)^{-\frac{1}{2}} dx = -\dfrac{1}{2}(u^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}dx = -\dfrac{1}{2u}dx$ such that $-2u du = dx$. By substitution, we have

$$\int \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{3-x}} dx = -\int \dfrac{(2u)(3-u^2)}{u} du=-\int (6-2u^2) du$$

Thus,

$$\int \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{3-x}} dx = -6u+\dfrac{2}{3}u^3 + C$$

Upon substitution of $u=\sqrt{3-x}$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{3-x}} dx &= -6\sqrt{3-x}+\dfrac{2}{3}(3-x)^{\frac{3}{2}} + C
\\
&=-6\sqrt{3-x}+\dfrac{2}{3}(3-x)\sqrt{3-x} + C
\\
&=\sqrt{3-x}\Bigg(-6+\dfrac{2}{3}(3-x)\Bigg)+C
\\
&=-\dfrac{2}{3}\sqrt{3-x}\Bigg(9-(3-x)\Bigg)+C
\\
&=-\dfrac{2}{3}\sqrt{3-x}(6+x)+C
\end{align}$$

Comment: OP has already got to this point in the working, they had issues with rearranging the solution afterwards

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \frac x{\sqrt{3-x}}dx$$ with $u^2=3-x$, i.e. $-dx=2u\,du$ gives

$$\int\frac{3-u^2}u2u\,du,$$ which is easy.

---

Alternatively,

$$\int \frac x{\sqrt{3-x}}dx=\int \frac{3-(3-x)}{\sqrt{3-x}}dx=\int \frac{3}{\sqrt{3-x}}dx+\int \sqrt{3-x}\,dx$$ is also elementary (powers of $a-x$).

Answer (score 0):

Substituting
$$t=\sqrt{3-x}$$ then $$dx=-2tdt$$ and your integral will be
$$\int\frac{3-t^2}{t}\cdot (-2t)dt$$

Comment: All of this is written in the question already, the issue was with rearranging the solution